# Where is IDA getting this symbol?

Tags: ida, c++, elf, symbols

I'm currently researching how a certain malware works and patches some stuff in a certain Android's library.

Inspecting the library -which is stripped- in IDA I was able to get the symbol for a certain function in it, but I can't get it through any other means (like `objdump -T -t`, `nm`, `readelf`, and executing `strings` on the binary doesn't throw that string). I'm quite familiar with the ELF format, and so I made a simple ELF parser just to try something else, but obviously it wasn't able to find the symbol either.

So now I just want to understand how IDA can get this symbol when it appears isn't contained in the binary. The only thing I can think of is that maybe IDA sees through other symbols the class this method belongs to and also the types of the arguments it receives, and thus can guess the symbol.

Comment: IDA uses FLIRT signatures to try and identify known library functions. You did not specify what the symbol is, if possible - add it, it will get you more accurate answers.

Comment: @Yotamz hmm, ok, that makes sense. I knew of the existence of some kind of database of routines, but also thought it would be used with a plugin or something like that... Now the question feels kind of dumb :/

Comment: what is the symbol name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(reposting as an answer)

IDA uses FLIRT signatures to try and identify known library functions.

Functions found in this way would normally be marked as *library function*s and will be displayed in IDA disassembly with a different color.